# Is it possible to name a CWinThread thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-c++, mfc

I have a C++ application (VS2008), and I start threads like this:

```
CWinThread *myThread= AfxBeginThread(myOp,0);
```

Now all I wan to do is name this thread, so I can identify it while debugging.

It sounds like a simple task, but I could not find the way to do it. Is this possible, and if so, how?

Comment: The `CWinThread` class doesn't have the ability to hold a name.

Comment: @trojanfoe It's not the `CWinThread` class that holds the name, it's the debugger that keeps track of it after it is sent a *magic* exception - see my answer.

Comment: @David Heffernan:  Interesting stuff; totally different to how, say, Java does it.

Comment: @trojanfoe: I think you'll find that, in general, the way things are done in C++ are "totally different" from how they're done in Java.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This can be done relatively easily as documented on [MSDN: How to set a Thread Name in Native Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xcb2z8hs.aspx).

Essentially you send the debugger a *magic* exception containing the name and the thread ID, and the debugger then keeps track of and displays the name you sent it.

The sample code from the MSDN article is included below:

```
//
// Usage: SetThreadName (-1, "MainThread");
//
#include <windows.h>
const DWORD MS_VC_EXCEPTION=0x406D1388;

#pragma pack(push,8)
typedef struct tagTHREADNAME_INFO
{
   DWORD dwType; // Must be 0x1000.
   LPCSTR szName; // Pointer to name (in user addr space).
   DWORD dwThreadID; // Thread ID (-1=caller thread).
   DWORD dwFlags; // Reserved for future use, must be zero.
} THREADNAME_INFO;
#pragma pack(pop)

void SetThreadName( DWORD dwThreadID, char* threadName)
{
   THREADNAME_INFO info;
   info.dwType = 0x1000;
   info.szName = threadName;
   info.dwThreadID = dwThreadID;
   info.dwFlags = 0;

   __try
   {
      RaiseException( MS_VC_EXCEPTION, 0, sizeof(info)/sizeof(ULONG_PTR), (ULONG_PTR*)&info );
   }
   __except(EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER)
   {
   }
}
```

Comment: +1 for *magic* exception. Although I would have added some sample code to the answer. The folks who run MSDN are fond of re-organizing things, and losing helpful links in the process.

Comment: Does anyone know if procmon (from sysinternals), can see these thread names?

Comment: I don't believe so. The names can only be seen by a process that is debugging the target process and I don't think procmon debugs the processes that it monitors.

Comment: "relatively easily" compared to what? Splitting an atom? ;o)